# DLL Incompatibility in various versions of visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, dll, linker, dllexport, incompatibility

I've a DLL file that is compiled with visual studio 2008 (suppose `stub.dll`), I know the exported function signatures of this DLL, but I don't know about it's internal implementation.
This DLL itself uses some other exported functions from another DLL which I should write (suppose `server.dll`)
I'm writing my `server.dll` in visual studio 2013 & export all desired functions correctly, my test programs can use exported functions without any problem, but when I want to use `stub.dll` it failes to load dynamic library.
Since I've no access to it's source, so I can't debug it to find where the problem is, but I guess it should be some kind of incompatibility between various versions of compiler or linker that I can't use `server.dll` within `stub.dll` (just about calling convention, I'm sure both of them use `_stdcall` calling convention).
any idea?

Comment: Show us the error message you are getting.

Comment: The `stub.dll` is a CSP dll & here is the error that I give: 0x8009001d (Provider DLL failed to initialize
correctly.)

Comment: Did you try to use Dependency Walker (Google it) to resolve the dependencies?

Comment: seems all dependencies are OK!